# Iterator through many queues with different types

Tags: c++, templates

I have many queues in which they always comes in pairs. Like queue A & B, queue C & D and so on

The queues are in different types but from one template class.Like

```
template<class objType>
struct myqueueType {
   objType obj;
   ....other content....
}

std::deque<myqueueType<int> > a;
std::deque<myqueueType<int> > b;

std::deque<myqueueType<double> > c;
std::deque<myqueueType<double> > d;

std::deque<myqueueType<float> > e;
std::deque<myqueueType<float> > f;
```

My target is to compare between a and b(then c and d, then ....)to see if they are the same. I can of course do the while loop 3 times for different pairs. But is there any smart way in case they are going to be many many queues like that.

Comment: Are queues come in pairs or values also come in pairs? In the later case - you can just store the pairs of values in one queue

Comment: Queues are always in pair. A and B are one pair. C and D are one pair.

Comment: I mean - does any entry in a has a pair in b and could they be added as std::pair to the same queue? So you will traverse one queue at a time using something like find_if

Comment: in the a, it will be like {0, 5, 10, 2, 3}
in the b, it will be like {0, 5, 10, 2, 3, 1} 
their content comes from different threads, I need to check if they are identical or not in the end. And the sequence shall be the same as well. Right now, I check the queue size first, and then iterator each element to check if it is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write templated function which expects two deques of type which you explicitly specify, so you may compare whatever elements you want.

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
bool CompareQueues(Container& first, Container& second)
{
    if (first.size() != second.size())
    {
         return false;
    }

    for (auto it1 = first.begin(),
              it2 = second.begin();
         it1 != first.end() &&
         it2 != second.end();
         it1++, it2++)
    {
        if (*it1 != *it2)  // Overload operator '!=' in 'myqueueType', or compare them as you wish
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Function call (for integers):

```
std::deque<myqueueType<int> > a;
std::deque<myqueueType<int> > b;
CompareQueues<int>(a, b);
```

**[See it live here.](https://ideone.com/qOEK0a)**